# Timeshift Question: loading a restore point, excluding software added after restoring

Tags: backup

I looked around and tried to read the documentation, but I am a bit new with Linux. And couldn’t understand it. I’m running the latest Pop!_OS and installed Timeshift.

I run into problems where I install new software incorrectly and then struggle to uninstall it. I want to use Timeshift in a way so that if I really mess up installing/uninstalling software, I can restore to an earlier “snapshot” without the new software being included.

I tried it once as a test (installed steam, then tried to restore from a restore-point made prior to installation of steam) but after restoring, steam was still installed.

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that,

> Timeshift [...] is designed to protect only system files and settings. **User files such as documents, pictures and music are excluded.**

(My emphasis.) This is important because it shows that Timeshift is not a complete backup system: your own files are not backed up and are therefore at risk.

If Steam is installed under your own account rather than as a system installed application then it is considered to be part of your user files. As such any restore from Timeshift will completely ignore it because there are no backups of your files to restore.

---

Personally, I don't understand the design decisions that led to a user-centric GUI-based "backup" tool intentionally excluding users' files, but that's how it is.

Comment: I see your frustration. Maybe I’ll choose a different backup software. If I’m understanding this right, my software (steam in this case) was still installed after I restored from my restore point because it’s installed into my user files. Right?

Comment: @ZhangBenKong I don't know for sure, but yes that would fit the situation

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: In TimeShift you have the option to backup user files it’s just not the default. You can change this in the main wizard. I believe the reason for this is is to prevent unintentionally removing recently created or modified user data. Consider the following. You make a backup, you create or modify some data, then you mess up your system. Sure you can revert to the backup but in so doing you lose the recent user data. If you remember it you can backup that user data but you might as well have a separate backup solution for data. Steam was an unfortunate test case, anything else would have been ok